# re-create a VM from a clone

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a VM on vSphere that I already created a clone for it. I want to script the following to execute remotely:

1. Delete the VM from vSphere
2. Create a new VM from the clone
3. Run a PowerShell script on the new VM once it is up and running.

Help with any of these is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are the PowerCLI commands for each request.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FRemove-VM.html

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FNew-VM.html

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Invoke-VMScript.html